# How to get response from HTTP Sink Plugin in Cloud Data Fusion?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, google-cloud-data-fusion, cdap

**Expertise**: I am new to Cloud Data Fusion.

**What I am trying to achieve**: Create a Data pipeline in the Google Cloud Data Fusion:

1. Read a file from GCS.
2. Call an HTTP Endpoint with the parsed data of GCS.
3. Save the response received from HTTP in the GCS file.

[image]

However, it seems HTTP Plugin(Sink) doesn't have the capability to receive the data back from the endpoint.

Comment: Could you please provide the error message, the version of your cluster, are u using private IP and where the http endpoint is located (publicly on the internet, on a private network)?

Comment: Can you please provide the error message?

Answer (score 1):

Probably you cloud fusion is on a private network, your http endpoint is exposed on the internet so you can contact it but you cannot receive the response. Cloud Nat is usually used for this kind of requirements.

Comment: Hi @MBHA, thanks for your valuable answer. Yes, my cloud fusion is on the private network and the target endpoint is hosted on the internet. Can we receive the data from HTTP Sink? Because it is meant for one-way communication right?

Comment: I think you're missing a Cloud NAT gateway : https://cloud.google.com/nat/docs/overview

Comment: I checked the logs the of the HTTP plugin it was able to receive the response, then it just checks if the status code is 200 and ignores the response due to which, I am not able to save the result to the GCS.